# Chrome Randomly Downloading Files from Onedrive

Tags: google-chrome, onedrive

I am running Google Chrome and Onedrive on an iMac 2017. Onedrive has on-demand files enabled, so that it only downloads files when I request them. I gave Chrome permission two days ago to download files when necessary, and this afternoon it started randomly downloading my files in a systematic order. I did not do anything that initiated a file transfer to Chrome, and it did not stop until I blocked its access. It downloaded a good portion of my Onedrive. Is this a known bug or a bigger issue?

Comment: Yes. I have seen the same issue on my Mac.